# Execute sql script in batch file with sqlplus command

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I want to execute a **PL/SQL** script from a batch file. After some research I wrote this:

```
sqlplus.exe %user%/%pwd%@%db% @c:\users\NDL\SQL\MHUHMS.sql %%l
```

where user, pwd and db are set before. But here I have to execute the script MHUHMS.sql with one parameter. And it seems that doesn't work; it's giving me an ORA-01017 error and then asking me the user and password. When I give the same values as I used in the batch file it doesn't execute my script.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

I've based this on a `sqlcmd` version:

```
SQLCMD -S touoracst01 -U %user% -P %pwd% -d %db% -v l ="%%l" -i c:\users\NDL\SQL\MHUHMS.sql
```

But there are some questions:

- Don't I have to pass the parameter `-S touoracst01` ?
- Is it the right conversion ? Or have I done something wrong ?

I dont' want to modify the SQL script, so I'm hoping the problem is only in the batch file.

EDIT : I modify my sqlplus command like this

```
sqlplus -L %user%/%pwd%@%db% < "c:\Hardis\NDL\SQL\MHUHMS.sql" %%l
```

I'm connect ! This part is ok, but it seems that my call of the **pl/sql** script is not good, with the parameters %%l. there is my loop : http://puu.sh/l1Kg2/f66d9c2aa7.png If someone can help me. Because the calling with parameters seems good....

Comment: Sounds like those % variables aren't set, or aren't valid; how are you checking? Do you get an error before it prompts you? Do you still get prompted if you use the `-l` flag?

Comment: I set this %variable before, at the beginning of the script. Yes it say to me that the logon was not recognize. but after i write the same user and password and it's works. I don't understand your last question, sorry i'm not an expert in batch file. Where i have to put the -l option ?

Comment: What is the exact error message? ORA-01017, ORA-12154, something else? Are you including the @db part when you try the second time? Would be useful to add exactly what you see and do to the question.

Comment: Ok i add some screen to explain more that a simple text !

Comment: I add text and pictures.I've got the ORA-01017 error like you said

Comment: When you just put `reflex` you don't have the `@db` part. You might not be connecting to the same database. With `@db` you're connecting using a TNS alias in your `tnsnames.ora` file, without you're connecting locally; so check what the file says, if it's the same machine you're on now, and if you have ORACLE_SID, TWO_TASK or LOCAL set? Otherwise you just have the variables wrong...

Comment: I use the tnsname yes. And i use the value of this file, exactly the same. the user and password are the same. So if my variable are "wrong" how can pass them ? in variable to ajust my script in different case

Comment: have you echo'd the line to screen so you can what it actually looks like at runtime?

Comment: You should provide more of your batch code; `%user%`, `%pwd%` & `%db%` seem to be environment variables that need to be set correctly like `set VAR=VALUE`; since some special characters may cause trouble, use `set "VAR=VALUE"`; *never* put spaces around the `=` sign; `%%l` looks like a `for` loop variable, but if it is not placed *inside* the related `for` loop, it is undefined (and will be parsed to `%l` literally)...

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Thk's for contrib. I echo'd my values and it's the value i affect in the beginning of my script.
@aschipfl Thk's, you allright it's environment variables and i set them at the beginning of my script like that `set user=reflex` the %%l is use in the loop : `for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%l IN ('type "%%f"') DO (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research i found this :

```
sqlplus -L %user%/%pwd%@%db% @C:\Hardis\NDL\SQL\MHUHMS.sql "%%l"
```

And the %%l is a variable of my loop. Thank's all for your help !